# bootstrap cards aren't adjusting height when one card gets more content

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I have 4 cards.
In a scenario from the backend for one card, there will be more text in one particular card. but the expected output is: If one card gets big content than other cards. all cards have to be at the same height and cards which don't have much content will be vertically aligned. (But that card's height should be the same as the big content card).
I used bootstrap cards and d-flex. but I couldn't achieve it.

Code Snippet

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center mb-5">Our other packages</h1>
            <div class="slick-swipe v-align-center-slick-contents">
                <div class="mr-3 p-2">
                    <div class="card text-center level-4 bg-1">
                        <div class="border-top-thick"></div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h6>Bigger Content Big Big</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="mr-3 p-2">
                    <div class="card text-center level-4 bg-2">
                        <div class="border-top-thick"></div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h6>Gold</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                

                <div class="mr-3 p-2">
                    <div class="card text-center level-4 bg-3">
                        <div class="border-top-thick"></div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h6>Thee</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="mr-3 p-2">
                    <div class="card text-center level-4 bg-4">
                        <div class="border-top-thick"></div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h6>Diamond</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="mr-3 p-2">
                    <div class="card text-center level-4 bg-5"> 
                        <div class="border-top-thick"></div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h6>More Packages</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a class in your css files to specify the height for the cards.

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center mb-5">Our other packages</h1>
  <div class="slick-swipe v-align-center-slick-contents">
    <div class="mr-3 p-2">
      <div class="card cards text-center level-4 bg-1">
        <div class="border-top-thick"></div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h6>Bigger Content Big Big</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mr-3 p-2">
      <div class="card cards text-center level-4 bg-2">
        <div class="border-top-thick"></div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h6>Gold</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mr-3 p-2">
      <div class="card cards text-center level-4 bg-3">
        <div class="border-top-thick"></div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h6>Thee</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mr-3 p-2">
      <div class="card cards text-center level-4 bg-4">
        <div class="border-top-thick"></div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h6>Diamond</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mr-3 p-2">
      <div class="card cards text-center level-4 bg-5">
        <div class="border-top-thick"></div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h6 style="font-size: 1.5rem;"> Vestibulum feugiat congue nulla vitae semper. Mauris id nibh nisi. Aliquam vel semper velit, sit amet hendrerit ipsum. Vestibulum sodales dictum ex vitae accumsan. Vestibulum varius ut mauris at iaculis. Suspendisse sodales pulvinar diam, non lobortis risus. Etiam sagittis convallis leo, a scelerisque eros laoreet et. </h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mr-3 p-2">
      <div class="card cards text-center level-4 bg-5">
        <div class="border-top-thick"></div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h6>More Packages</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

```
.cards {
  height: 200px;
}
```

[Here is an example](https://codepen.io/dkounga/pen/MWbwLPm)

Comment: No , we do this like harcoding the height. What if datas come from backend dont have much content . (E.g: data come for all cards like this  - A,B,C,D etc ) . We will get unwanted height

Comment: Bootstrap 5 - This link may help someone - https://codepen.io/Kerrys7777/pen/QWgwEeG